# org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ResultProcessingException: Could not parse response

Tags: junit, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have created a new Maven Project:

https://github.com/neosamples/neosamples

where I gradually copy content from:

https://github.com/luanne/flavorwocky

to better understand how it works and which dependencies are needed. For now I would like to just make it possible to unit test adding new items to a GraphRepository. Currently my project has this layout:

[image]

Where:

**Application.java**

```
package com.samples.neo4j;

 ...(imports)

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.samples.neo4j")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("com.samples.neo4j.repository")
public class Application extends Neo4jConfiguration {

  final String grapheneUrl;

  public Application() {
    grapheneUrl = "http://neo4j:neopass@localhost:7474";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration getConfiguration() {
    org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration config = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration();
    config.driverConfiguration().setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver").setURI(grapheneUrl);
    return config;
  }

  @Override
  @Bean
  public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(), "com.samples.neo4j.domain");
  }

  @Override
  @Bean
  @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
  public Session getSession() throws Exception {
    return super.getSession();
  }
}
```

Where **neo4j** is the user and **neopass** is the password I am using when accessing:
http://localhost:7474/browser/

And:

- [PersistenceContext](http://pastebin.com/iA0Nb3xt)
- [MyNode](http://pastebin.com/cuF1kf57)

I am trying to run this unit test in:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { PersistenceContext.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)

public class ServiceTest {
  @Autowired
  MyNodeRepository nodeRepository;

  @Autowired
  Session session;

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    session.purgeDatabase();
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    MyNode n = new MyNode("test");
    nodeRepository.save(n);
    MyNode node = IteratorUtil.firstOrNull(nodeRepository.findAll());
    assertNotNull(node);
  }
}
```

But when I run the unit test above I get the below error in the console:

```
2016-07-19 12:39:41,571  WARN o4j.ogm.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest: 235 - Caught response exception: Unauthorized
2016-07-19 12:39:41,596  WARN o4j.ogm.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest: 235 - Caught response exception: Auth scheme may not be null
```

and this stack trace:

http://pastebin.com/tK42AqtW

I have been tried to customize my pom dependencies for quite some time, but I get the feeling that I am running in circles, below is my current configuration:

http://pastebin.com/5vt2EBdu

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you configure SDN? Do you have an ogm.properties or is it Java configuration? Please share the config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your auth credentials aren't quite right. If you've taken the flavorwocky config, then it's not clear what your GRAPHENEDB_URL represents. Perhaps modify your code to configure the URI directly like this:

Application.java

```
config.driverConfiguration().setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver").setURI("http://neo4j:password@localhost:7474");
```

(Replace the neo4j username/password/host/port with whatever you're using)

**Edit:**

The problem is this dependency which is not compatible with the drivers used by SDN 4.1.2:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-drivers</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-M02</version>
    <scope>test</scope>         
</dependency>
```

You don't need to include the dependency on the HTTP driver. But if you're using Embedded or Bolt, then you need to include these (documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#_dependencies_for_spring_data_neo4j_4_1))

If you remove this dependency, then there is no longer an authentication problem, but your test will still fail because `MyNode` cannot be instantiated- it requires a no-args constructor.

For the unit tests, I recommend following flavorwocky and using the embedded driver. You would need to include the [appropriate ogm.properties file.](https://github.com/luanne/flavorwocky/tree/sdn-4.1/src/test/resources)

Comment: Yes I did try that too. I have updated the example based on your suggestion to make it more clear. But yes seems to be an Authorization problem don't understand why since its the same credentials I use when logging into http://localhost:7474/browser/ from the browser.

Comment: Strange. If you have your code somewhere on github I can take a look